# LetsEncrypt - "Can't connect to the client for DV"

Tags: server, ssl, openssl

I am using [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) on Ubuntu 15.10.

I have opened ports `443` and `80` using UFW and can access the domain (akuk.co.uk) I'm trying to secure in web browsers from HTTP.

When running the `./letsencrypt-auto` command and selecting the domains (akuk.co.uk and www.akuk.co.uk), I receive the following message:

> Failed authorization procedure. www.akuk.co.uk (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client for DV :: Failed to connect to host for DVSNI challenge
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>
> - The following 'urn:acme:error:connection' errors were reported by
>     the server:
>
>   Domains: www.akuk.co.uk
>     Error: The server could not connect to the client for DV

---

Running `./letsencrypt-auto --verbose`, I see:

> Generating key (2048 bits):
>   /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0026_key-letsencrypt.pem
>   Creating CSR: /etc/letsencrypt/csr/0026_csr-letsencrypt.pem
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
>   Performing the following challenges:
>   tls-sni-01 challenge for akuk.co.uk
>   tls-sni-01 challenge for www.akuk.co.uk
>   Enabled Apache ssl module
>   Waiting for verification...
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
>   Reporting to user: The following 'urn:acme:error:connection' errors
>   were reported by the server:
>   Domains: www.akuk.co.uk
>   Error: The server could not connect to the client for DV
>   Cleaning up challenges

---

My `ports.conf` file looks like this:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

---

The `sites-enabled` file `akuk-co-uk.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@akuk.co.uk
        ServerName www.akuk.co.uk
        ServerAlias akuk.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/akuk_co_uk/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# Server Settings for Port 443 (SSL)
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@akuk.co.uk
        ServerName www.akuk.co.uk
        ServerAlias akuk.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/akuk_co_uk/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

With the ports `80` and `443` open, I can't understand the issue; how can this be fixed?

Comment: The machine you're running this on is the actual webserver for akuk.co.uk?  Because letsencrypt puts a file in .well-known/acme-challenge/ inside your webroot folder of the machine you are running the program on and then tries to connect to that file remotely to verify you do indeed control the domain.

Comment: Yes it is - there is an `A` record for `akuk.co.uk` that directs to the IP (188.221.***.**). Could *letsencrypt* be creating the file into the wrong folder? (There are multiple folders under `/var/www/html`; `akuk.co.uk` points to `/var/www/html/akuk_co_uk/public_html`

Comment: You can also run letsencrypt as a standalone webserver by the way. I've used that on my server to get certificates since I use Nginx and that needs some tweaking to get to work. You need to stop Apache (or Nginx) while running letsencrypt. The command you would need after stopping Apache is: ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone --agree-tos --redirect --duplicate --text --email admin@akuk.co.uk -d akuk.co.uk -d www.akuk.co.uk

Comment: EDIT - I've added the `.conf` file for that site

Comment: @Limecat Thanks for your advice. I stopped `apache2` and ran the command - it provided the *exact same* error: `Running with virtualenv: /home/ben/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt certonly --standalone --agree-tos --redirect --duplicate --text --email webmaster@akuk.co.uk -d akuk.co.uk -d www.akuk.co.uk
Failed authorization procedure. akuk.co.uk (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client for DV :: Failed to connect to host for DVSNI challenge`

Comment: I think your DNS settings are wrong. www.akuk.co.uk resolves to 188.221.xxxx.xxxx and akuk.co.uk resolves to 94.126.xxx.xxx

Comment: You can of course just ask for a cert only for akuk.co.uk, but then you need to remove the -d www.akuk.co.uk from the letsencrypt line

Comment: You were right - I realised that one of the two were pointing away from my server. I changed it and managed to generate the certificate. Thanks! How can I now use this cert to implement HTTPS?

Comment: You need to set Apache to use your new cert! It should be located in /etc/letsencrypt/live/akuk.co.uk/ Just search google for a guide. There is one here you can use (just skip the self signing parts, and of course you should not get a warning because you have valid certs!) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've not managed it yet but you've really put me on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to forward port `*:443` on my **router** to the relevant IP on my network (192.168.0.23, in my case)